# AEM Transform not working -Content dam asset transform is not transforming image dynamically

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have an asset(.jpg) stored in content/dam .. I am trying to dynamically transform that image by using named image transform factory(i.e 3D150 which resize it to some x width and height)

Example : My asset location
/content/dam/asset/xyz.jpg So if i use something like this /content/dam/asset/xyz.jpg.transform/3D150/123.jpg i am expecting 123.jpg to be rendered in the resize mentioned in named image transform factory. I tried to debug it i do see that it does hit this servlet com.adobe.acs.commons.images.impl.NamedTransformImageServlet. But it finally gives me a page not found error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one hint before I start:
Giving AEM version and ACS Commons version might help... I hope you have ACS commons installed..?

It looks like you did the naming wrong. The documentation says you need to add the following things to your supported resource URI:

1. .transform suffix (you did that correctly)
2. name of your transform config - needs to be set in OSGi config (MISSING)
3. /img or /image (MISSING)
4. .{YOUR_IMAGE_EXTENSION} (correct)

So that would then lead to a URL like /content/dam/asset/xyz.jpg.transform/123/img.jpg
If your config is stored as /123.

Please see https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/named-image-transform/index.html for a detailed documentation.

Comment: acs-aem-commons-bundle-4.3.2-  This is the bundle version that i have installed .. And i am using AEM 6.5 . And yes i have a transform config setup with this name 3D150. and i tried this /content/dam/asset/xyz.jpg.transform/3D150/img.jpg ..It isnt working - And the above link is what i am referring too!

Comment: then you should add that to your question in the first place. Apart from that you wrote "So if i use something like this /content/dam/asset/xyz.jpg.transform/123.jpg" which is not what you say now and not at all what it should be...

Comment: shoot!! Didnt realize that i had the transform name missing in my question and missed the referring documentation too!! But other than this is there any other config which might be causing it not to work ?

Comment: I do not think so. I just tried with my own 6.5 and http://localhost:4502/content/dam/wknd-events/lance-asper-152203-unsplash.jpg.transform/test-name/img.jpg - works like a charm. But I had ACS 4.7.0, maybe there is a bug with the old version.

Comment: Thanks!! Oliver i had some typo !! But this works /content/dam/asset/xyz.jpg.transform/123/img.jpg ..I had some issue with my osgi config!!